# Insert multiple rows in Msaccess using single insert statment - Sql

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA. I am using the ms-access as database. I  have a raw data in excel, I want to insert the data to ms-access daily basis.
In every excel i have more than 100 or 200 rows. My database and excel column headers are same. 
Now I am insert one row at time. It takes too long time to insert all data's. Instead of that i want to insert all rows in one insert statment.

**Currently I am the following method:**

```
for i = 1 to 100
name = wb.sheets(1).celss(i,1)
job = wb.sheets(1).celss(i,2)
testt = wb.sheets(1).celss(i,3)

ssql="insert into (name, job, testt) values('"& name &"','"& job &"','"& testt &"')"

next i
```

the above method takes too long to insert all the datas. Can anyone help me to push all data's using one insert statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered importing the entire sheet using 'DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tblFromExcel", strFilePath, True'  - requires matching column headers to field names?  From your sample, you are not changing the input values, so it should be simple.

Comment: You can also use DAO/ADO  recordsets.

Comment: Hi currenly I am using Adodb databased connectivity. How can I insert whole worksheet at a time using single insert query.

Comment: I believe @4dmonster was suggesting you open the table as a recordset, then in your loop, do rs.add  rs!FldA = name ... rs.Update  That would be faster than the SQL insert query

Comment: you could make the sheet a linked table and insert from that too

Answer (score 0):

If the first row of your worksheet is headers you can query the spreadsheet directly from access. The select values are your column header names.  `Sheet1` is your sheet name as it appears in excel and that $ is necessary in your access query.

```
Dim dbLocal as DAO.Database
Set dbLocal = CurrentDB()
Dim sql as String 
sql = "INSERT INTO Table1 (name, job, testt) SELECT name, job, testt" & _
      "FROM [Sheet1$] IN '" & FileName & "'[Excel 8.0;];"
dbLocal.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
dbLocal.Close
Set dbLocal = Nothing
```